# In Unity, use motion capture positions and rotations in csv to move rigid body

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, physics-engine, rigid-bodies

I am dealing with motion capture data (CSV files with 6DOF information about the 3D locations and rotations of markers over time) and I want to use this marker data to manipulate rigid bodies and skeletons.

For example, I have a ring that has 5 markers on it. I have the 6DOF of each marker over many frames, and I have a mesh of a ring of the same size. How can I use the information of the markers' positions and rotation values over time to manipulate the rigid body's position? I've tried using joints and rigid bodies from Unity's physics engine but haven't gotten anything to work properly yet. My main issue has been getting it to rotate properly..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you already know how to calculate the desired goal position and rotation for your virtual mesh ring from the marker positions of the real ring data?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Yes.. I want the mesh ring to follow the marker positions of the real ring data exactly

Comment: As you already know the exact desired position and rotation then, can you just use `rigidbody.MovePosition` and `rigidbody.MoveRotation`? If you tried that and it didn't work, do you have an animation to show us the issue?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Since there are 5 different points (markers) that I want to control each part of the wheel, but no way to tell these points which part of the wheel to manipulate, how would you recommend I go about doing that? I could add bones to the wheel at those specific points and make each of those a rigid body, but I was encountering problems where it was not rotating and treating the whole wheel as a rigid body

Comment: Can you post a picture illustrating what you have so far? And ideally, an animation that shows what's currently happening?